# Link two mics to one mic

Tags: audio, microphone, asio, fl-studio

I have FL studio, using the FL Studio ASIO driver, and my microphone.
I want the FL studio to output to my headphones and a VB-Virtual Cable audio input.

I want my mic also to output to VB-Virtual Cable then I want to connect my discord and game audio to the mic called VB-Virtual Cable Output
I don't really want to use a different ASIO driver, but if required I will use a different ASIO